# iOS - Trigger.io - How to get product price for in-app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, trigger.io

Apple recently changed his currency conversion rates, which puts the synchronization between prices in our app and the real prices invalid. So I figured there must be a way to get this price information dynamically. I googled a little to find out that `SKProductsRequest` is the way to get the price information from apple store. But I'm not using Objective-C, but trigger.io. is there a way to get this information with Trigger.IO? I can't seem to find any related method in Payments module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no method in [Trigger.io's payments module](https://trigger.io/modules/payments/current/docs/index.html) to get price information for inapp purchases. I've added this functionality using a own native module and `SKProductsRequest`, however this code is not published yet. I'll send it over to Trigger.io and maybe they will be happy to implement it in their official module.

Comment: Thanks, I hope they implement it soon :)